# Array to string conversion in named route group in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

My named route group is working fine without resource route. But when I am trying to use 'resource route' then getting this error. Would someone help me please, in where I am doing wrong?
My Route Group is -

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
   Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminController@dashboard'));

   Route::group(['prefix' => 'student', 'as' => 'student.'], function () {
      Route::resource('admission', array('as' => 'admission', 'uses' => 'Admin\StudentController'));
}); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass resource controller name as string as the second parameter for `Route::resource()`:

```
Route::resource('admission', 'Admin\StudentController');
```

You don't need to specify routes names with `'as' => 'admission'` because the `Route::resource()` will do that automatically.

Comment: If I declare as you said then, I did not get route like 'admin.student.admission'.

Comment: @RashedHasan [`Route::resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) will create 7 routes for you. Looks like you want to gave just one, so use `Route::get()` like `Route::get('admission', ['as' => 'admission', 'uses' => 'Admin\StudentController']);`